# Vertical spacing discrepancy with \usepackage{titleps} vs \usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}

Tags: titlesec, vertical-spacing, titleps

**Edit (context added)**
In a personal class which makes use of `titleps`, I'd like to switch to `titlesec` for its `\ifthesection` feature. For backward compatibility, there shouldn't be any visual difference. But, as shown by the following MCEs, there is a vertical spacing discrepancy with `\usepackage{titleps}` vs `\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}`. The tiny difference in the header is not a big deal but more important is the vertical shift of the text. How to get rid of it?

### MCEs

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}

\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

### Diff (thanks to `diffpdf`)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made a few experiment. Instead of `blindtext` I used `lipsum`.

### First file

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{titleps}
\showoutput
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Heading on level 0 (chapter)}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

### Second file

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\chapter{Heding on level 0 (chapter)}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

### Third file

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\chapter{Heding on level 0 (chapter)}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

### Results

There is no difference in output between second and third. There is difference between first and second and the same differences appear between first and third.

### What's happening?

If loaded alone, `titleps` patches `\chapter` and the other sectional titles. This is not needed if it is loaded along `titlesec`. This leads to small differences in how the chapter header is typeset.

Comment: The differences in how the chapter header is typeset are indeed small. But more annoying is the vertical shift of the following text.

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I guess some “whatsit” enters the scene when the title has more than one line.